# Why is the image processor script not working in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

As an extension to my last question, I just discovered the image processor script in CS6 to batch resize images. Seems simple enough - I apply to a folder with these settings:

[image]

And yet the output for the few screenshots I have saved in that folder is all over the place!!

[image]

Not only are all these images (and they're definitely the right ones - taken from the new output folder that was created) different sizes from that specified in the script dialog, but the third, colourful one, scales as I increase the size of the preview window, whereas the others don't.

This seemed like such a simple thing to do, but apparently I can't manage it... :/

Can anyone please say what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: scaling within the OS preview window is completely unrelated to this and should be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

This is a terminology issue.

Resize to Fit = Shrink to the first maximum reach of the following W and H sizes.

So if your image is very tall you'll hit the H limit first, and the aspect ratio won't be changed so the H limit will be exactly as you specified but the W much less than your limit.

And Vice-Versa.

As to the Preview scaling as you resize the window, that's probably because you have Preview's View set to Zoom to Fit.

Comment: Command + 0 [in Preview] will give you "show me the actual size of this image" and is probably the best shortcut in all of Mac OS X. Certainly one I use more often than just about anything other than Command + Spacebar to launch Spotlight to use as a launcher.

Comment: "resize to fit" also means *scale UP* to fit, not just shrink.

Comment: It should never be used for scaling up.

Comment: That may be true, but it does do it.

Comment: Thank you guys. So if I'm trying to simply get images to fit a certain pixel size (W & H), regardless of how they start out, what's the way to do this?

Comment: "FIT" means that there'll be some loss, or some fudging of extra "content" to make it fit. That's why I'm suggesting to change the Canvas size to the correct size in the other question, then you can push around the content to fit as best as it will. This will not be automatic because of the Aspect Ratio issues.